# Type Error when removing a child and removing it from an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I get a type error(a term is undefined and has no properties) in the following function when the bullet hits the spartan

> bullets is an array
>
> spartans is an array

and this function basically moves the bullets and the Spartans while checking if they are colliding and if they are the are both removed.

```
function loop(event:Event)
{
    for (var bcount=0; bcount < bullets.length; bcount++)
    {
        if (bullets[bcount].x <= 1055)
        {
            bullets[bcount].x = bullets[bcount].x + bulletSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            removeChild(bullets[bcount])
            bullets.splice(bcount, 1)
            bcount--
        }
        
        for (var spcount=0; spcount<spartans.length; spcount++)
        {
            spartans[spcount].x = spartans[spcount].x - spartanSpeed
            if (bullets[bcount].hitTestObject(spartans[spcount]))
            {
                removeChild(spartans[bcount])
                spartans.splice(spcount, 1)
                spcount--
                removeChild(bullets[bcount])
                bullets.splice(bcount, 1)
                bcount--

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you define the arrays? Before or after you added the event listener for your loop function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

in the second loop I think you want to remove spartans[spcount]

So change this line

```
 removeChild(spartans[bcount])
```

To

```
  removeChild(spartans[spcount])
```

**Second**

In the second loop you should check if bcount is less than zero. Because in the first loop and second loop, you both reduce bcount, so bcount could be -1.

For example, bullets[0]'s x is bigger than 1055, so bcount would be -1. And if this not happen, in the second loop, if the collisions happen in some times, bcount  will be less that 0.